# How to solve a stiff ode with Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, ode

I'm a Python beginner. I'm trying to switch some programs that I have in matlab.
I need solve a stiff ode equation, whose inputs are all matrices. In matlab I use

```
[ttT,uT] = ode23s('SST',t,fT);
```

Comment: Can you describe it with mathematic notation as well? Not everyone is familiar with matlab.

Comment: This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088473/integrate-stiff-odes-with-python

Comment: ode23s is a solver to stiff equations in Matlab
in this example, SST is an aux function, which stablish a State-Space relation, z = A * z + B, A and B are matrixes. A is square and B is column.
t is an array with temporal increments and fT is an array with the initial conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most things you do in Matlab, you can do them with the NumPy module in Python. It can be found [here](https://numpy.org/).

You might also find the related module [SciPy](https://scipy.org/) useful as well.

[PyDSTool](https://web.archive.org/web/20190811214900/http://www2.gsu.edu:80/%7Ematrhc/PyDSTool.htm) might also be of relevance to you. It's a wrapper around the Radau solver.

Then you might like to try [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) for plotting. It works quite like Matlab's plotting thing.

The following links might help, too:

- [http://www.ews.uiuc.edu/~mrgates2/ode/](http://www.ews.uiuc.edu/%7Emrgates2/ode/)
- http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific?action=show&redirect=SciPy
- [Integrate stiff ODEs with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088473/integrate-stiff-odes-with-python)

Comment: Thank you very much. I already installed numpy and scipy.
With google, I found the mrgates page. However, I don't know how to install his "module". I think Gates' approach turns everything simpler.

i'm not EPD subscriber.

Comment: The last link, I'm sorry, but it's too fuzzy for me. I didn't understand which is useful or not! I "just" want a simple thing, but I'm figure in python, it isn't !

Comment: To install Gates' module follow these steps: 1) Unzip the archive. 2) Say you unzipped into C:\ode-0.1a4.tar. Confirm that there's a file called 'setup.py' inside this folder. 3) Now open the commandline at this folder and run this command: 'python setup.py install'. This should install the module on your machine. Now you can go and import this module and use it as Mr. Gates describes on his page.

Comment: Sorry about the EPD link in case it requires subscription. I'll remove it.

Comment: I've added links to PyDSTool and matplotlib modules. Do take a look at them too.

Comment: Thank you @Frederick .
I'm looking careful to all of this information.
I think, my primary goal is solve. (get an array of results). I think "gates way" is the best.
I did "python setup.py" in the folder and module installed with some warnings.

Comment: On aptana I use the following sample code from http://www.ews.uiuc.edu/~mrgates2/ode/ . But module isn't "resolved".

Comment: All information that you gave to me is useful to Switch from matlab to Python. However, If I'm not able to solve ode, I can't switch at all =)

Answer (score 1):

If you show me the differential equations I can help you a little more, but in general, a good way to solve a stiff ODE system is through the next sentence:

```
solution = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(function, [t_0, t_f], y0, method='BDF', first_step =0.0001, dense_output=True)
```

where your function has to be defined previously in this way: function(t,variable,parameters)

```
t_0 = initial value for time
t_f = final value for time
y0  = value of your variables at t_0
```

For stiff ODE system, I suggest use the method 'BDF' (is typically used in the solve of microkinetic systems in reactors, where the importance of the time could change a lot)

for more infomation about the options of the code: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html