# splitting an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that is `(219812,2)` but I need to split to `2 (219812)`.

I keep getting the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (219812,2) (219812)`

How can I accomplish?

As you can see, I need to take the two separate solutions from u =  odeint and multiple them.

```
def deriv(u, t):
    return array([ u[1], u[0] - np.sqrt(u[0]) ])

time = np.arange(0.01, 7 * np.pi, 0.0001)
uinit = array([ 1.49907, 0])
u = odeint(deriv, uinit, time)

x = 1 / u * np.cos(time)
y = 1 / u * np.sin(time)

plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the ith column of a 2D array, use `arr[:, i]`.

You could also unpack the array (it works row wise, so you need to transpose `u` so that it has shape (2, n)),  using `u1, u2 = u.T`.

By the way, star imports aren't great (except maybe in the terminal for interactive use), so I added a couple of `np.` and `plt.` to your code, which becomes:

```
def deriv(u, t):
    return np.array([ u[1], u[0] - np.sqrt(u[0]) ])

time = np.arange(0.01, 7 * np.pi, 0.0001)
uinit = np.array([ 1.49907, 0])
u = odeint(deriv, uinit, time)

x = 1 / u[:, 0] * np.cos(time)
y = 1 / u[:, 1] * np.sin(time)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

It also seems like a logarithmic plot looks nicer.

Comment: @dustin Make sure you're not computing/plotting something else. This shows how to "split" an array, which I think answers your question. We won't be able to help you solve your other question without more information.

Comment: @dustin Do you want `plt.plot(time, u[:,0])`?

Comment: @dustin There are possibly a few other problems with your script, and if you are interested in getting it to work, you should ask another question about the actual problem you're interested in solving.  One thing I notice is that your `deriv` equation accepts a `t` argument and never uses it. Also it is splitting the arrays by row, not by column.

Comment: @askewchan [numerically solving odes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928750/numerical-ode-solving-in-python)  Here is a link to another method of solving it but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to index into the tuple:

```
foo = (123, 456)
bar = foo[0] # sets bar to 123
baz = foo[1] # sets baz to 456
```

So in your case, it sounds like what you want to do might be...

```
u = odeint(deriv, uinit, time)

x = 1 / u[0] * np.cos(time)
y = 1 / u[1] * np.sin(time)
```

Comment: that returned the same error I am getting: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2) (219812)`

Comment: It would be useful to mention that error in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

```
u1,u2 = odeint(deriv, uinit, time)
```

maybe ?

Comment: @dustin Then try `u1, u2 = odeint(deriv, uinit, time).T`.